# How to add header content to Material-UI's DataGrid Export to CSV?

Tags: material-ui

I would like to add header content to `Material-UI`'s `DataGrid` `Export to CSV` feature. The `Export to CSV` only exports the contents of the table, but I'm working on a project where the client needs attribution and metadata added to the csv contents. By header content I mean additional string content that is not part of the table data. The content I am looking to add is basic string data and would likely only amount to a few lines.

I'm also open to using the paid `XGrid` version if that would allow for this.

Any thoughts or ideas for how to achieve this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The API method [getDataAsCSV()](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/export/) allows you to get the CSV as a string. Then, you can replace the Export CSV Button with a custom one which will call `getDataAsCSV()`, add the metadata to the string and save it.

If you think this is a good-to-have feature, you can open an issue to add metadata as an argument of `CsvExportOptions`.